# How do I call my "counting()" function from within the "question()" function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I call my “counting()” function from within the question() function? So that I only need to specify that it should be run once - no matter how many questions I have in my quiz game.
I have tried, but nothing is working.

Please help me, thank you.

p.s my questions are on Swedish, but they don't matter.

```
    from time import sleep
        
        def main():
            option()
            
        def start_menu():
            
            """This will display the main menu"""
            print("*"*40)
            print("MAIN MENU")
            print("*"*40)
            print("1. Start the quiz") 
            print("2. Statistics")
            print("3. Exit game")
        
        def option():
            """This should get user input """
            while True:
                start_menu()
                option= input("Write your choice here [1-3]")
                if option=="1":
                    qustion_game()
                elif option=="2": 
                    statistics()
                elif option=="3": 
                    game_over()
                    return
                else:
                    print("he selection you specified was not valid, [1-3]")
        
        def qustion_game():
            """Frågesporten"""
            print("♡"*40)
            print("Welcome to this quiz ")
            print("♡"*40)
            print("")
        
            sleep(1)
            question("Annika hade 4 barn, den första hette januari, den andra hette februari, tredje hette april, vad hette den fjärde.?", "vad")
            print("")
            counting()

           
        
            sleep(1)
            print("♡"*40)
            question("Vem får lön utan att jobba en enda dag i hela sitt liv?", "nattvakt" )
            print("")
            counting()
           
        
            sleep(1)
            print("♡"*40)
            question("Lägg till 1000 till 40. Lägg till 1000. Lägg till 30. Lägg till 1000 igen. Lägg nu till 20. Lägg till 1000 igen.Lägg nu till 10.Vad är svaret?", "4100")
            print("")
            counting()
           
          
        
        
        def question(quiz,quiz_answer):
            """Outputen av frågor"""
            user_guess=input(quiz)
            while user_guess != quiz_answer:
                print("Sorry, try again...")
                fail_answer()
                user_guess=input(quiz)
            print("")
            print("*"*40)
            print("Correct")
         
            
        
        def statistics():
            """Provides the user with statistics on how many questions they have answered and how many errors they have made """
            print("Statistics")
            print("*"*40)
            
            print("You have totally answered " + str(answered) +" questions") 
            print("Off " +str(answered)+ " answer, have you answered incorrectly on " + str(fail))
        
        
        def fail_answer():
            """prints how many questions the user has answered"""
            global answered
            answered = answered + 1
        
        def counting():
            """prints how many errors the user has made"""
            global fail
            fail = fail + 1
           
        def game_over():
            """Exit the game"""
            print ("Game over, see you next time")
        
        fail = 0
        answered = 0
        main()
```

Comment: why does `def` have a tab in front of it?

Comment: Its possible the SO editor wasn't used effectively. @Andy_ye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for you to solve this issue is by a class, that can maintain its internal state. Then, you can call the function as many times you want and it will keep an internal state of your variables. Then you can call *class.failed_answer()* as many times as the user fails your question and it will always continue from that point, avoiding resetting your variable no matter how many questions you have.

Full code (as the question author asked in comments) would be this:

```
from time import sleep

class Statistics:
    def __init__(self):
        self.answered = 0
        self.failed = 0

    def counting(self):
        self.answered += 1

    def failed_answer(self):
        self.failed += 1

def main():
    option()

def start_menu():
    """This will display the main menu"""
    print("*"*40)
    print("MAIN MENU")
    print("*"*40)
    print("1. Start the quiz")
    print("2. Statistics")
    print("3. Exit game")

def option():
    """This should get user input """
    stats = Statistics()
    while True:
        start_menu()
        option= input("Write your choice here [1-3]")
        if option=="1":
            qustion_game(stats)
        elif option=="2":
            statistics(stats)
        elif option=="3":
            game_over()
            return
        else:
            print("The selection you specified was not valid, [1-3]")

def qustion_game(stats):
    """Frågesporten"""
    print("♡"*40)
    print("Welcome to this quiz ")
    print("♡"*40)
    print("")

    sleep(1)
    question("Annika hade 4 barn, den första hette januari, den andra hette februari, tredje hette april, vad hette den fjärde.?", "vad", stats)
    print("")



    sleep(1)
    print("♡"*40)
    question("Vem får lön utan att jobba en enda dag i hela sitt liv?", "nattvakt", stats)
    print("")


    sleep(1)
    print("♡"*40)
    question("Lägg till 1000 till 40. Lägg till 1000. Lägg till 30. Lägg till 1000 igen. Lägg nu till 20. Lägg till 1000 igen.Lägg nu till 10.Vad är svaret?", "4100", stats)
    print("")

def question(quiz, quiz_answer, stats):
    """Outputen av frågor"""
    user_guess=input(quiz)
    stats.counting()
    while user_guess != quiz_answer:
        print("Sorry, try again...")
        stats.failed_answer()
        user_guess=input(quiz)
    print("")
    print("*"*40)
    print("Correct")

def statistics(stats):
    """Provides the user with statistics on how many questions they have answered and how many errors they have made """
    print("Statistics")
    print("*"*40)

    print("You have totally answered %d questions" %stats.answered)
    print("Off %d answers have you answered incorrectly on %d" %(stats.answered, stats.failed))

def game_over():
    """Exit the game"""
    print ("Game over, see you next time")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If I implant this, I can remove counting () under the questions in question_game? Thank you

Comment: Yes. You can add this function in the question() function, as each time you call question() it will also call your counting() function as well. Then you can call it one last time in the statistics() function and decrease its value by 1 and it'll give you the correct value of answered questions.

Comment: I tried to add it to the code, but I didn't work, I think I added it wrong. I wonder if you could do an edit on my code,  with the yield keyword?

Comment: Editted my answer with the full code. If it solves your problem, please tick it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate that you are helping me. I tried the code again but I wonder why this one is implied  if __name__ == '__main__:
    main()?The code didn't work

Comment: It had a typo on it, just edited to make it correct. This if __name__ == '__main__': main() is a good practice on your python scripts. We can easily call it directly by executing it from the terminal and it will point out to the __main__ function, executing your main(). But this approach doesn't exclude the possibility of importing it in another module and using it as a external library if you want it in future uses.

Comment: Can you help with this error :TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'generator' and 'int'

Comment: Added a more advanced code to better clarify the solution. It's now tested and it works perfectly. I changed from using *yield* to *class*, because it suits your problem better :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to unindent the whole of your code.

Additionally, it seems that your functions `fail_answer` and `counting` are doing the wrong things - they need to be swapped around.

```
def fail_answer():
    """prints how many errors the user has made"""
    global fail
    fail = fail + 1

def counting():
    """prints how many questions the user has answered"""
    global answered
    answered = answered + 1
```

Apart from that, your code is working in its existing form, if you also just insert a call to `counting` from inside `question` after printing `Correct`:

```
def question(quiz,quiz_answer):
    ... existing code goes here ...
    print("Correct")
    counting()
```